I need help with this basic discrete math problem
I am unclear of what the question is trying to ask me to do, so I only need some hint plz.
Let s be a string of length 2 with characters from $\{0, 1, 2\}$, and define statements a, b, c, and d as follows:
a = “the first character of s is 0”
b = “the first character of s is 1”
c = “the second character of s is 1”
d = “the second character of s is 2”.
Describe the set of all strings for which each of the following is true.

a. $(a\lor b) \land (c\lor d)$
b. $(\sim (a\lor b)) \land (c\lor d) $
c. $((\sim a)\lor b) \land  (c\lor (\sim d))$


It's asking for a list of strings for each of the three conditions written in propositional form. Replace each $\vee$ with "or" and each $\wedge$ with "and" (being careful to observe the grouping provided by the parentheses), and write down the list of strings that satisfy the resulting condition. To avoid down-votes and close-votes, you're best off at least trying to do this, and asking for specific help if you get bogged down. Good luck!

For example the first one is "the first character is 0 or 1 and the second character is 0 or 1". You have to describe strings satisfying those conditions.

Each string is of length 2, and each character of the string can be chosen from any of the 3 characters in $\{0,1,2\}$. So there are a total of $3^2 = 9$ possible strings. I would suggest you start by enumerating all of these strings.
To make it clearer, you could make a truth table:



$s_1$
$s_2$
$s$
a
b
c
d




0
0
00
T
F
F
F


0
1
01
T
F
T
F


0
2
02
T
F
F
T



The question is just asking you to list the $s$ that satisfy the two given conditions.
As an example, the set that satisfies $a \vee b$ is $\{00,01,02,10,11,12\}$

Answers
a. $(a \vee b) \wedge (c \vee d): $
$\rightarrow \{00,01,02,10,11,12\} \cap \{01,11,21,02,12,22\} = \{01,02,11,12\}$
b. $\sim(a \vee b)) \wedge (c \vee d): $
$\rightarrow \{20,21,22\} \cap \{01,11,21,02,12,22\} = \{21,22\}$
c. $((\sim a) \vee b) \wedge (c \vee (\sim d)) : $
$\rightarrow \{10,11,12,20,21,22\} \cap \{00,01,10,11,20,21\} = \{10, 11,20,21\}$
